# Sum the values of groups of 4 contiguous columns in R

Tags: r, sum

Starting from a table of 372 columns and 12,000 rows in R, I need to create a new table with columns that contain rows with the sum of same row from columns 1:4, then 5:8, then 9:12, and so on up to column 372 of the original table. Here a short example:

Input:

```
m = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 7L,
+ 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(2L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2"), c("a", "b",
+"c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")))
```

Which looks like this:

```
    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
r1  3  2  3  1  1  2  3  1
r2  1  6  1  8  5  1  7  1
```

Expected output:

```
    A  B
r1  9  7
r2  16 14
```

So, A = a+b+c+d, and B=e+f+g+h. Easy to do with a small table in Excel. Columns a-d correspond to a group, e-f to another, if that helps.

Comment: You will probably need to `dput` that object to make this reproducible as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/ Otherwise, you might have an object with any of a number of distinct classes (data.frame, matrix, table). For example, you might edit `m = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
7L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(2L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2"), 
    c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")))` into your question if you have a matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Frank. I already edited my question.

Answer (score 4):

The question is currently underspecified, but supposing you have a matrix...

```
m = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
7L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(2L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2"), 
    c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")))
```

Make your column mapping:

```
map = data.frame(old = colnames(m), new = rep(LETTERS, each=4, length.out=ncol(m)))

  old new
1   a   A
2   b   A
3   c   A
4   d   A
5   e   B
6   f   B
7   g   B
8   h   B
```

And then `rowsum` by it:

```
res = rowsum(t(m), map$new)

  r1 r2
A  9 16
B  7 14
```

We have to transpose the data with `t` here because R has `rowsum` but no `colsum`. You can transpose it back afterwards, like `t(res)`.

Comment: If you really are making names like A, B, ... and have 374 columns, of course you'll run out. In this case, you could use pairs of letters (for 26^2 combinations): in place of `LETTERS` in the answer, write `do.call(paste0, expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS))`

Comment: Thanks Frank. This worked, including this last suggestion for LETTERS. Although my object is a list. Should we change that in our question/answer?

Comment: @fibar Hm, I'm not sure what you mean by a list here, but I'd say go ahead and add it if you think it's relevant.

Answer (score 3):

A base R solution, suppose `df` is your data frame:

```
cols = 8
do.call(cbind, lapply(seq(1, ncols, 4), function(i) rowSums(df[i:(i+3)])))
#    [,1] [,2]
# r1    9    7
# r2   16   14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a vectorised way if you transform your original data to a matrix with 4 columns, then use rowSums on that, and then transform it back to match the rows of the original data frame. Here it is in one long command

```
    df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
            3  2  3  1  1  2  3  1
                1  6  1  8  5  1  7  1")

    matrix(rowSums(matrix(as.vector(t(as.matrix(df))),
         ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)), ncol = ncol(df) / 4, byrow = TRUE)

    #      [,1] [,2]
    #[1,]    9    7
    #[2,]   16   14
```

Edit: To preserve the row names, if e.g. `rownames(df) <- c("r1", "r2")`, just apply them to the resulting matrix (the row order is preserved), ie run `rownames(result) <- rownames(df)`.

Comment: It would be nice to have the `r1`, `r2` labels preserved, I guess. Not sure if that would happen here, since you excluded them from your input.

Comment: @Frank I thought these were just row names. These can be added back at the end, I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
df <- data.frame(t(matrix(colSums(matrix(t(df), nrow=4)),nrow=nrow(df))))
##  X1 X2
##1  9  7
##2 16 14
```

1. First transpose the data to a `4 x (ncol(df)/4 * now(df))` matrix where now each column is a group of four columns for each row in the original data frame.
2. Sum each column using `colSums`
3. Transpose the data back to a data frame with the original number of rows